# Deezer Javascript SDK /playlist/me/tracks returns error

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, deezer

I am trying to add a song to the users favourite tracks like this:

```
addFavourite(song) {
    DZ.api('/playlist/me/tracks', 'POST', { songs: song.id, order: 1 }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
{
   code:800,
   message: "no data",
   type: "DataException"
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you have to use is not "/playlist/me/tracks" but "/user/me/tracks".